# Retaining Firebase offline database even when app is killed

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I've implemented the Firebase offline capabilities using `setPersistenceEnabled(true)` and `keepSynced(true)`.
The offline data works just fine as long as the app isn't killed but as soon as I kill the app and restart it, all the data has to be download again. **Whats the best and easiest way to cache that data to make it usable across app restarts?**
One of the naive approaches I thought was to store all of the downloaded data in a .txt file and read from it if the app is restarted and isn't online.
Again, I'm looking for an efficient way to store the data for reading it offline.

This is my 'WearResults' activity where I'm setting the persistence to true:

```
public class WearResults extends Application{


    @Override
    public void onCreate(){

        super.onCreate();
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);

    }
}
```

This is my Manifest's Application tag where I've put 'WearResults' in the name property:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/neurosticlogo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme"
    android:name=".WearResults">
```

Comment: Calling `setPersistenceEnabled(true)` will persist the data to disk, which means that it should survive an app restart. If that doesn't work for you, share the [minimal, complete code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've edited the question, posted the code.

Comment: That code enables persistence so that recently read data and any pending writes are stored on disk. What doesn't work?

Comment: Precisely. I want this data to be present in the disk even when I kill and restart the app.